# How can I get the content type of a node given its node ID?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a URL like *track-new/15/51*. `arg(2)` returns `51`.

How can I check if the content type of the node whose ID is `51` (the value returned from `arg(2)`) is `'artist'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the value returned from `arg(2)` is a node ID, you can load the node with `node_load()`. This will return a node object, which contains its content type.

```
$node = node_load(arg(2));
$content_type = $node->type;
```

Comment: `drush php-eval '$node = node_load(51); return $node->type;'`

Answer (score 2):

Although I am a big fan of `node_load()`, it is possible to get the `type` of a node from a node `nid` in a more resource friendly way. Here's a helper function to get a node's `type` given a `nid`:

```
/**
 * Given a node id, this returns the node's type or NULL if it doesn't exist.
 * @param $nid
 * @return {String|NULL}
 */
function example_get_node_type($nid) {
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('type'))
    ->condition('n.nid', $nid)
    ->execute();
  $result = $query->fetchObject();
  return $result->type;
}
```

Then you can use it with something like:

```
if (example_get_node_type(arg(2)) == 'artist') {
  // Do something...
}
```

Or if you already have the node id, something like this:

```
$nid = 123;
if (example_get_node_type($nid) == 'artist') {
  // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`menu_get_object()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) to retrieve data loaded by the current menu-router item. In your case you can get to the node like this:

```
$node = menu_get_object('node', 2);
$node->type;
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of validation before calling **node_load** is never harmful:

```
if (arg(2) && is_numeric(arg(2)) {
    $node = node_load((int) $a2);
    $type = $node->type;
}
```

Comment: Fixed a couple small issues in the code: 1. The `isset()` was being done on the entire condition rather than just `arg(2)`, and 2. you can't do an `isset()` on the return of a function (ie. return value in write context).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$menu_item = menu_get_item();

    // Test if this is a term page.
    if (!strncmp($menu_item['path'], 'taxonomy/term/%', 15)) {
        $obj = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to get a node from its node ID that is passed in the URL. It's not asking about taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 0):

If the route for that path is, for example, track-new/%/%node or track-new/%user/%node, I would use the following code.

```
if ($node = menu_get_object('node', 2)) {
  $content_type = $node->type;
}
```

If the route for that path is, for example, track-new/%/% or track-new/%user/%, I would use the following code.

```
$nid = arg(2);
if (!empty($nid) && is_numeric($nid) && ($node = node_load($nid))) {
  $content_type = $node->type;
}
```

`menu_get_object('node', 2)` doesn't work with a route like track-new/%/% because it expects the load function for the last part of the path to be `node_load()`, which isn't true for a route like track-new/%/%.
In fact, the code used from [`menu_get_object()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7.x) is the following one.

```
  $router_item = menu_get_item($path);
  if (isset($router_item['load_functions'][$position]) && !empty($router_item['map'][$position]) && $router_item['load_functions'][$position] == $type . '_load') {
    return $router_item['map'][$position];
  }
```

I would always use `node_load()` when I want to load the node object associated with the current path independently from how the route has been defined.

I am using `node_load()` instead of querying directly the database because:

- It's possible that I would need other node properties, even if that could happen in future versions of the module I am writing
- The nodes loaded with `node_load()` are cached in memory, which means that the code I am using could not even cause any database query